# ¿Cómo hacer que mi App en Vue Cli sea soportado en cualquier navegador?

Tags: vue.js, axios

Tengo un proyecto en Vue cli:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y decidí agregar [Vuetify](https://vuetifyjs.com/es-MX/)

Tengo un botón que me debería comprobar los datos del usuario y hacer el login.
Pero no funciona en móviles, sólo en web. En mi navegador anda perfectamente, pero en teléfono no anda. Le doy al botón y no hace nada...

Pienso es que no soporta las nuevas funciones de fechas u otras características de ES6... Utilizo `.then()` con [axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios) y no sé si pueda ser eso...

**¿Cómo pasaría de ES6 a ES5?**

Instalé Babel pero no logro transpilarlo, mi `babel.config.js` es:

```
module.exports = {
  presets: [
    '@vue/app'
  ]
}
```

¿Cómo le agrego el preset es ES5 para que pueda transpilarlo?

También hice uso de `vue-cli-service build --modern` para como dice en la [pagina oficial](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/browser-compatibility.html#modern-mode) me haga dos versiones, uno para navegadores antiguos y otro no. Pero igual :(

** Axios lo cargo como librería externa ya que al usar NMP me dice que axios es undefined, no sé por qué....

Aquí mi package.json:

```
{
  "name": "application",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "vue": "^2.5.17",
    "vue-google-oauth2": "^1.2.0",
    "vue-recaptcha": "^1.1.1",
    "vuetify": "^1.3.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.6.1",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^3.2.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "^3.2.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "^3.2.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.1",
    "eslint": "^5.8.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^5.0.0-0",
    "node-sass": "^4.11.0",
    "sass-loader": "^7.1.0",
    "stylus": "^0.54.5",
    "stylus-loader": "^3.0.1",
    "vue-cli-plugin-vuetify": "^0.4.6",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.5.17",
    "vuetify-loader": "^1.0.5"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "root": true,
    "env": {
      "node": true
    },
    "extends": [
      "plugin:vue/essential",
      "eslint:recommended"
    ],
    "rules": {},
    "parserOptions": {
      "parser": "babel-eslint"
    }
  },
  "postcss": {
    "plugins": {
      "autoprefixer": {}
    }
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not ie <= 8"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Pero.. el cli de vue hace todo esto automaticamente y solo. transpilar, meter axios, todo solo. No se porque estas haciendo todo a mano. Tal vez deberias usar el CLI para inicializar el proyecto y solo copiar tus componentes?

Comment: Vue CLI no mete axios, y no transpila a ES5... Me meto en el app.js que genera al compilar y sigo viendo funciones de flecha

Comment: lo de axios tenes razón.. (mala mia ahi, agrega tantas cosas que me olvide que axios no). lo otro no se que decirte.. nunca tuve problemas con eso. tu navegador no tira errores al ejecutar el codigo no? en la consola?

Comment: podrias mostrar tu package.json a ver si tiene algo raro ahi? lo de axios me extraña mucho...

Comment: Lo de axios lo estoy resolviendo, es que no hice el `import axios from 'axios'`, y bueno actualizo para el package.json

Comment: podrias hacer un [mcve] para que veamos cual es el problema tambien?

Comment: @Jonathan la solución no va en el cuerpo de la pregunta, eso es in correcto; si ya tienes la respuesta entonces usa la zona para ello debajo de tu pregunta y ahi explica como lo resolviste

Comment: Oka no sabia, gracias. No lo fueses borrado para copiar y pegar :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La solución estuvo en seguir la guia de [Vuetify para navegadores antiguos](https://vuetifyjs.com/es-MX/getting-started/quick-start#ie11-support)

Permitiéndome pasar funciones de flecha a funciones normales.

`() => { ... }` > `function(){ ... }`

En cuanto a lo de axios, tuve que importar la librería y declararla global...

```
import axios from 'axios';
window.axios = axios;
```